# Twig_Error_Loader - directory does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this error when deleteing cache.

`sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

```
 [Twig_Error_Loader]                                                                                                                                                 
  The "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist ("/Use  
  rs/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/Resources/views").
```

I deleted all vendor/* and reinstalled by composer, but this error continues.

`sudo php app/console cache:clear`

This command shows no error.

Comment: Do you use spool in swiftmailer or real-time sending?

Comment: @mikes I use pool

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove cache manually - `rm -rf var/cache/*`
2. Clean spooled emails `rm -rf SPOOL_DIRECTORY/*`, by default `rm -rf var/spool/*`

Both from project root directory.